# XML Parsing & T-SQL -- Part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

The last of my XML Parsing & T-Sql questions for a while.
I have an xml field with data such as below:

```
<Criminal xmlns="http://schemas.somewebpage.com/data/stuff">
  <MessageContent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Content>Content in here!!</Content>
    <Type>Empty</Type>
  </MessageContent>
</Criminal>
```

This code does not seem to be working:

```
SELECT
Content = XmlContent.value('(/Criminal/MessageContent/Content)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Type = XmlContent.value('(/MessageContent/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @table
```

...and only returns NULL.

Suggestions?

Comment: does it work if you remove the xml namespace attributes in the xml?

Comment: I removed the :xsi and :xsd namespace (if that was what you were referring to) and got an error.  Then I removed all namespace references all together till was only left with:

    Criminal>
      <MessageContent>
        <Content>Content in here!!</Content>
        <Type>Empty</Type>
      </MessageContent>
    </Criminal>

and my select statement worked.  Only when the use of 3 namespaces did it cause problems for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespaces are tripping you up.  You are also missing "/Criminal" in the 2nd part of the query.  Try something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://schemas.somewebpage.com/data/stuff' as ns2,
  DEFAULT 'http://schemas.somewebpage.com/data/stuff'
  )
SELECT
Content = XmlContent.value('(/ns2:Criminal/MessageContent/Content)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
Type = XmlContent.value('(/ns2:Criminal/MessageContent/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @table
```

Results:

```
Content             Type
Content in here!!   Empty
```

Comment: That did it!  Must remember to declare the namespaces.